# Flex property of CSS hides scrollbar in WebChat

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a webchat widget that I am downloading through a URL, but I need to style the widget so the bottom of the scroll bar always shows the most recent messages. I found a way to do this with CSS, but it's not quite there yet.

If I add `display: -webkit-flex;` I get exactly what I need, but the chat window width gets mysteriously shortened in width. I've tried adding width properties but they are ignored when I run it.

[image]

Then if I use `display: -webkit-flex;` and `flex-direction:column-reverse`, the width stays the full width of the container it's in and the focus is at the bottom like I wanted, but the scrollbar disappears, so the user is not able to view past messages. I have also tried some javascript methods, but those seem to get ignored as well when I add them to my script in my `.pug` file.

[image: Scrollbar gone]

How do I get my chat window to keep the scrolled focus at the bottom (to see new messages without scrolling) and still be able to manually scroll to the top again to see old messages? I am open to a solution in either CSS, HTML, or JavaScript. Since HTML is easy to get into a Pug format, I will include it as a tag, even though I use Pug for my UI.

**index.pug**

```
 chat-window
      #webchat(action='/chat', method='POST')
      script(src='https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js')
      script.
        const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
          bubbleBackground: 'rgba(252, 229, 53, 1)',
          bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(4, 234, 104, 1)',
          paddingRegular: 10,
          sendBoxHeight: 50,   
        });
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }),
        styleSet
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

**main.css**

```
chat-window {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #000080;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #5a8cb1;
    height: 350px;
}

#webchat {
    max-height: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not surprised there are no responses, since the widget itself is its own beast that is likely affecting any CSS or Javascript, complete with its own styling. Although some of the CSS did work, so it was worth a shot to ask. There were not many options with styling with the widget, but I did manage to find a work around. It's not visually as great as I'd hoped, but it does extend the webchat window to a greater width. I realized the reason it truncated when I added the `display: -webkit-flex;` was because it was being "flexible" to the chat bubble text. So when I enter longer text, it will widen. So I found some minimal styling options for the webchat itself, through the [WebChat widget from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleSetOptions.js). I made the bubble width larger, so it will at least display a larger webchat box when longer text is entered:

[image]

This is a good workaround that will suffice. The chat window starts out more narrow (until longer text is entered), but I can deal with that. But it does stay wide after it has been widened, so that is at least good. Plus, I don't lose the scrollbar, which is essential.

**Final code:**

main.css

```
#webchat {
    max-height: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

index.pug

```
chat-window
  #webchat(action='/chat', method='POST')
  script(src='https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js')
  script.
    const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
      bubbleBackground: 'rgba(252, 229, 53, 1)',
      bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(4, 234, 104, 1)',
      paddingRegular: 10,
      sendBoxHeight: 50,  
      bubbleMinWidth: 400,
      bubbleMaxWidth: 700
    });
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }),
    styleSet
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```